# Hypertarget within an embedded .tex file

Tags: hyperref, pdf, embedding

I am creating a PDF from multiple latex files.
Within my `mainFile.tex` file I am embedding other `.tex` files using `\input{embeddedFile.tex}`. I want to create a hyperlink to a line in `embeddedFile.tex` from `mainFile.tex`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{filecontents}


\begin{filecontents*}{test.tex}

\section{include}\label{sec:test}

I am included text. \hypertarget{testlink}{Linktarget}

\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\input{test}

\clearpage

See \ref{sec:test}.

Use the following link \hyperlink{testlink}{Click me}

\end{document}
```